# Ultra-low Power DC DPDT Switch: Does It Exist?

Tags: microcontroller, switches, integrated-circuit, low-power

I'm working on a circuit for an ultra-low power microcontroller and two configurations are given for RFO HP and LP to operate in low and high power modes respectively. I tracked down an application note for using both and they recommended using DC switches (or solder bridges for a static configuration) and presented the diagram below.

[image: The reference.]

The design already includes [this load switch](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/FPF1504-D.PDF) and I was hoping to find something similar but for toggling a connection instead of interrupting it. The image below shows my ideal solution.

[image: What I want]

I have been searching for a similar ultra-low power IC but haven't even been able to find any SPDT switches, let alone DPDT.

Does this device (or another low power solution) exist?

Comment: Typically this would be done with distinct switches, especially as most of the time you may not want to have *either* on.  What's the transmit current?   Typically the switch's *active* power is nothing compared to the transmitter, it's whatever load it presents when not active which would be a concern.  An FET is fairly good in both respects though...

Comment: Some parts are available with both control input polarity possibilities, so you could run a pair of those with a single signal if you really aren't interested in a "both off" case.

Comment: Sadly lacking in details: voltage switching levels, current switching levels, control voltages, tolerable leakage currents?

Comment: How often do the switches have to change position? If it's very rare, then a latching relay might be worth considering.

Comment: @ChrisStratton It needs to be either "both-on" or "both-off" only. In my application continuous (or average) power consumption by the switch IC of more than around 1 μW would be too high.

Comment: @Andyaka Voltage levels would be no more than 3.3V, Current less than 150mA non-continuously, Control voltages also 3.3V and leakage as low as possible.

Comment: @ThePhoton Unfortunately it's hard to say as it depends on transmission range but I would be concerned about initial coil current with an EM relay. The entire device will be around 20x20 mm so size may also be an issue.

Comment: What does "as low as possible" mean numerically?

Comment: @Andyaka Preferably less than 2-3 μA

Comment: Have you looked at SPDT multiplexers?

Comment: No I hadn't, this seems to be much closer to what I am looking for. I am assuming two of these controlled by a single signal would work the way I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Voltage levels would be no more than 3.3V, Current less than 150mA
> non-continuously, Control voltages also 3.3V and leakage as low as
> possible.*

What does "as low as possible" mean numerically?

> *Preferably less than 2-3 μA*

Something like this maybe: -

[image]

Pick your own from [this selector page](https://www.analog.com/en/parametricsearch/12830#/p4683=%7C(2:1)%20x%202&sort=546,asc). Choose (2:1)x2 for device configuration to enable the choices.

Maxim and TI will have similar offerings.

Comment: That looks perfect, thank you. I thought I was going crazy trying to find this going through filters to search for this and thinking "surely this exists".

Comment: Leakage for that device is really low too. Maybe a tad expensive from ADI but you get what you pay for. TI might be cheaper.